# How to clone git repository from one machine to another in linux?

Tags: linux, git, redmine

I want to clone git repository from another computer but it gives me a message of:

*did you run git update-server-info on the server?*

what should I do? Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: What command are you executing to try to make your clone?

Comment: I'm using this command:  git clone http: //myserver/home/redmine/git_repositories/testproj.git

Comment: If you're doing this between machines you control, over a local network, ssh might be a lot easier: `git clone user@host:path/to/repo.git`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jefromi suggested, use

```
git clone redmine@myserver:/home/redmine/git_repositories/testproj.git
```

(update your username and "myserver" to real ones)

Answer (score 1):

It maybe that you are cloning over HTTP which is a dumb protocol and requires `git update-server-info` to be run. Try running `git update-server-info` on the server as the message suggests and re-clone.

Comment: It might be worth adding that using the sample post-update hook is a good way to make this happen automatically after someone pushes to the server's repository...